# Banach fixed point theorem application for f(x)=3πx-cos(pi*x/2)

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

I feel extremly stupid right now.

So we did Banach fixed point theorem and i thought i got it.

Basically if an intervall maps onto itself and is monotonous and contracts then you have a unique fixed point on that interval. Now we found an excercise on the internet that does neither and still we are supposed to prove the existence of a fixed point via Banach.

The function in question is [this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kebBP.png) and the interval is [0,1]. the iteration would be g(x)=f(x)+x

So i tried but neither of the edges map onto the interval [0,1] with g(0)=-1 and g(1)=3π+1

and the contraction via derivative is a total wash since the derivative at no point drops under 6.

Im starting to feel like i completely misunderstood something

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the inverse function is a contraction.

Comment: so i could just have the inverse which would swap x and y? and that would work because the fixed point would be from both sides (sorry for duzzy language, english isnt my native tongue)

Comment: If $f$ is a one-to-one function, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have the same fixed points.